# Password prompt in new window

Tags: c#, wpf, passwords

In WPF, I have created a separate Window to contain my password prompt that will be displayed on startup. The MainWindow needs to be disabled, running only when a correct password has been entered. I have done the following for my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this.view_model = new MainViewModel();
   this.DataContext = view_model;

   LoginWindow login_window = new LoginWindow();
   login_window.ShowDialog();
}
```

In the LoginWindow, a password is entered and the login logic is held in a Button click:

```
private void button_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Tuple<bool, string> result = view_model.Login(this.textbox_password.Password);
   if (result.Item1 == true)
   {
      // Login successful
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show(result.Item2, "Failed", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
   }
}
```

My question now is, how do I notify the MainWindowViewModel that it can proceed with the rest of the application? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to hook onto the MainWindow Initialized event to open a login window before the main window.

```
    private void MainWindow_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*** Start Login ***/
        new LoginWindow(this).ShowDialog();
    }
```

then in the login window call a Login Method, here AttemptLogin

```
    private void loginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Disable login button to avoid multiple login attempts
            loginButton.IsEnabled = false;
            m_mainform.AttemptLogin(UNtextBox.Text, PWpasswordBox.Password, otherID1, otherID2, this);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            loginButton.IsEnabled = true;
            //Login Error - Report error

        }
    }
```

then only when Attempt login callback has been verified allow the main methods to be called

```
    private void LoginCheck(API.LoginResp resp, CustomAsyncStateContainer state)
    {
        try
        {
            //Process response
            if (resp.header.errorCode != APIErrorEnum.OK)
            {
                //Login Failed - Show error if login failed
                if (loginForm == null)
                    new LoginWindow(this).ShowDialog();
                else
                {
                    loginForm.Activate();
                    loginForm.loginButtonEnabled = true;
                    loginForm.PWpasswordBox.Password = null;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (loginForm != null)
                {
                    loginForm.Close();
                    //Continue with Main App
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              //Log error
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a question about the implementation. So in the login button click event, you are calling a login method in which ViewModel? The ViewModel for the login window or the main window? And the LoginCheck() method is where? I haven't encountered any of the code in the LoginCheck() method before.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it can be any ViewModel or a class. The LoginCheck actually calls an external API which is why the AttemptLogin and LoginCheck callback are separate. Also, you will need to handle the LoginForm closing event to check that a successful login/session has been established and close the MainWindow if not.